# Can I get accepted to an university after cancellation of application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states

I have been accepted to an US university as an
International student under some condition like submission of English proficiency test. Now, at the beginning of semester I did not have the English score and I withdrew my application. Now, I have the score. Can I apply to the program against my application as I have withdrawn?

Answer (score 4):

You can ask ask, but any decision is up to them and only them. The problem is that the slot you were given may have been filled in the interim and there may be no room. If funding was involved it would be more serious as the funding limits are probably firmer than the number of slots available.

It might be especially difficult for doctoral admissions, but not necessarily impossible.

But ask and you will know. Do it fast.

Comment: Sounds more like they wish to resurrect their application, now that they have the test score. However, it is unclear. But your answer is correct - they should ask and see what happens. Given Covid, the 'requirement' may well have been waived anyway...